# Glossary link's color

Tags: hyperref, color, glossaries

How can I change the color of glossary links when using `glossaries` along with `hyperref`? I just want to change glossary link colors not all links.

Comment: Do you use the option `colorlinks=true`. If yes the color can be set via `linkcolor=blue`.

Comment: Yes, but it changes color of all links like table of contents and references (`/ref`). I just want to change the color of glossary references(`/gls`).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Normally the link color is set via the option `linkcolor` of the package `hyperref`. To influence only the link color of [`glossaries`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) you must redefine the command `\glstextformat`. In the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) you can find:

> The way the link text is displayed depends on
>
> ```
> \glstextformat{⟨text⟩}
> ```
>
> For example, to make all link text appear in a sans-serif font, do:
>
> ```
> \renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\textsf{#1}}
> ```

In relation to this comment here an example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\textcolor{green}{#1}}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{A}{name={A}, description={A is A}}
\newglossaryentry{AA}{name={AA}, description={AA is AA}}
\newglossaryentry{B}{name={B}, description={B is B}}
\newglossaryentry{C}{name={C}, description={C is C}}
\newglossaryentry{CC}{name={CC}, description={CC is CC}}

\begin{document}
Here I cite either \gls{A}, \gls{AA}, \gls{B}, \gls{C} or \gls{CC}.
I want three groups in the glossary output, indicated by \textbf{A},
\textbf{B} and \textbf{C} with entries in them according to their initial letter.

\printglossary[style=indexgroup]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar request, with the only difference that I didn't want to have any colored glossary links at all. Marco's solution wasn't satisfying for me as it changes all links to a specific color. Instead I wanted to keep the corresponding current text color.

---

Another approach might be setting the hyperlink color to the current text color (`.`) before the hyperlink is created and resetting it to the globally used link color (`\@linkcolor`) afterwards in a new command:

```
\newcommand*{\glsplainhyperlink}[2]{%
  \colorlet{currenttext}{.}% store current text color
  \colorlet{currentlink}{\@linkcolor}% store current link color
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=currenttext}% set link color
  \hyperlink{#1}{#2}%
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=currentlink}% reset to default
}
```

Then, override the existing `\@glslink` to use our command:

```
\let\@glslink\glsplainhyperlink
```

---

Complete example with a black link on white background and a white link on a black background:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=green]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\glsplainhyperlink}[2]{%
  \colorlet{currenttext}{.}% store current text color
  \colorlet{currentlink}{\@linkcolor}% store current link color
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=currenttext}% set link color
  \hyperlink{#1}{#2}%
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=currentlink}% reset to default
}
\let\@glslink\glsplainhyperlink
\makeatother

\makenoidxglossaries
\newglossaryentry{GPU}{name={GPU}, description={Graphics Processing Unit}}

\begin{document}

  I need a faster \gls{GPU}.

  \colorbox{black}{\color{white}I need a faster \gls{GPU}.}

  \printnoidxglossary

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on oreiche's solution, it might be a bit cleaner to define the `\glsplainhyperlink` macro like this:

```latex
\newcommand*{\glsplainhyperlink}[2]{%
    \begingroup%
      \hypersetup{hidelinks}%
      \hyperlink{#1}{#2}%
    \endgroup%
}
```

This way there is no need to save and restore the current link/text colors, as you simply tell hyperref to disable all link decorations. The grouping is needed to make the setup only affect the group as otherwise all following links in the document would be invisible.

---

Complete example (shamelessly stolen from oreiche :) ):

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=green]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\glsplainhyperlink}[2]{%
    \begingroup%
      \hypersetup{hidelinks}%
      \hyperlink{#1}{#2}%
    \endgroup%
}
\let\@glslink\glsplainhyperlink
\makeatother

\makenoidxglossaries
\newglossaryentry{GPU}{name={GPU}, description={Graphics Processing Unit}}

\begin{document}

  I need a faster \gls{GPU}.

  \colorbox{black}{\color{white}I need a faster \gls{GPU}.}

  \printnoidxglossary

\end{document}
```