# what .bib files do for bibtex, is there something for \href?

Tags: luatex, organisation, definition, href

I wasn't even sure how to formulate this question, nor the appropriate tags, so there may be some editing or even deletion if this is a stupid question... But I think it is a feature that people would want...

---

Often I find myself writing informative (I hope) documents that need `\href{addr}{name}` to provide more content. I know I could do it once, but then the reader has to hunt for the word among many pages to "go there".

It would be nice if I could just rely on a list of them, like in a .bib file, that a new definition could just provide the same functionality.

Silly example... Instead of this;

```
I like the search engine \href{https://duckduckgo.com}{duckduckgo} because \href{https://duckduckgo.com}{duckduckgo} provides me with privacy I don't really understand.
```

something like this;

```
I like the search engine \hrefcite{DDGo} because \hrefcite{DDGo} provides me with privacy I don't really understand.

(where there are a list of these items, e.g. `\newcommand{\DDGo}[1]{\href{https://duckduckgo.com}{DuckDuckGo}}`)
```

Maybe there is something like this already... I've used `glossary` before but I don't see how that helps either.

---

Currently, what sort of works is having the external file, `/home/me/somewhere/hrefListForInput.tex` under `\input` in the preamble of my main file, `main.tex`, e.g. `\input{/home/me/somewhere/hrefListForInput}`. In `hrefListForInput.tex` are things like

```
\newcommand{\DDGo}[0]{ \href{https://duckduckgo.com}{DuckDuckGo } }%
\newcommand{\foam}[0]{\href{https://sourceforge.net/projects/foam-extend/}{OpenFOAM }}
```

and in `main.tex`, I use these definitions like,

```
I like using \foam in \DDGo.
```

The 'sort of' problem manifests because if I don't put a space after the last letter in the 2nd argument of `\href`, it runs into the next word. If I do put a space, like I've written, it is fine except at ends of sentences where there is a weird space before the last word and the period.

Earlier I had an error whereby I needed to append the file extension, `.tex` to `hrefListForInput.tex`.

I'm using LuaLatex/Linux/TeXLive, an `article` document class, and so could use `\directlua` or things like that but a more universal approach would be better.

Comment: Oh, my bad... I guess it needed a `.tex` file extension... Now it works.  But is there still a better method? Or is this it?

Comment: how about glossaries? can it present a hyper ref in its `\gls` command?

Comment: I'm no expert, but on here, https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Glossary I couldn't find a way for any of the *gls* stuff to do anything but print out text....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `biblatex`. The easiest might be to define your own cite command

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\hrefcite}{\usebibmacro{prenote}}{%
    \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \href{\thefield{url}}{\printfield{label}}%
}{\multicitedelim}{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{foam,
  url          = {https://sourceforge.net/projects/foam-extend/},
  label        = {OpenFOAM},
}
@online{DDGo,
  url          = {https://duckduckgo.com},
  label        = {DuckDuckGo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  I like using \hrefcite{foam} in \hrefcite{DDGo}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, with the right spacing in the middle or at end of sentence - of course, it was `biblatex` ;)  Funny how I didn't have to `\usepackage{filecontents}`...

Comment: @nate the [`filecontents`](https://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents?lang=en) package enhances the standard environment a little.

Comment: okay, Thank you! Still reading pg 167 of http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf. Fascinating...

Answer (score 1):

You can add your urls to a bib file and then use biblatex. If needed you can define more cite commands (I once made one which inserted also the qr-code for such an url).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\citeurl{ctan} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I discoverd my above method doesn't add a space between it and the next word - great though at end of sentence. So looked at http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf and tried many different 'cites' but didn't see anything like \href{address}{print this}... Is there something in biblatex that could do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use glossaries to store and print your links:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{allLinks.tex}
\newglossaryentry{LINK1}{
    name={\href{https://www.overleaf.com/}{Linky link}},
    description = {\url{https://www.overleaf.com/}}
}

\newglossaryentry{LINK2}{
    name={\href{https://www.sharelatex.com/}{Link linky}},
    description = {\url{https://www.sharelatex.com}}
}
\end{filecontents}




\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\input{allLinks.tex}

\makeglossaries


\begin{document}
\section{One}
Texidy texti text \gls{LINK1} text text
\section{Two}
and also \gls{LINK2}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This example is of a file with two links, you can change the way the list is printed using all the styles available for the glossaries package.

Using this MWE the links will be displayed as plain text. If you want them to be formatted as links take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392724/90297

Comment: That's really nice! If it wasn't for the extra overhead - I sometimes don't need `glossary` but always need `biblatex`. Love the backref too. I see now about putting `\href` inside, here the `name` field of a glossary entry...